# is str_random unique in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I use `str_random(60)` function to generate a password reset code. my question is what about if thousand of people asked for resetting password is this code unique or it could be duplicated?

```
public function postForgotPassword(){

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('email'=>'required|email'));

    if($validator->fails()){

        return Redirect::route('account-forgot-password')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }else{

        $user= User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'));

        if($user->count()){

            $user = $user->first();

            $code = str_random(60);
            $password = str_random(10);

            $user->code = $code;
            $user->password_temp = Hash::make($password);

            if($user->save()){

                Mail::send('emails.auth.forgot', array('link'=>URL::route('account-recover', $code), 'username'=>$user->username,'password'=>$password), function($message) use($user)

                    {$message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('your new pass');

                    });

                    return Redirect::route('home')->with('global', 'we have sent you an new password');


            }
        }

    }

    return Redirect::route('account-change-password')->with('global', 'could not reset password');
}


public function getRecover($code){

    $user = User::where('code', '=', $code)->where('password_temp', '!=', '');

    if($user->count()){

        $user = $user->first();

        $user->password = $user->password_temp;
        $user->password_temp = '';
        $user->code = '';

        if($user->save()){

            return Redirect::route('home')->with('global', 'your account has been recoverd');

        }

    }

    return Redirect::route('home')->with('global','could not recover you password');
}
```

Comment: The source would indicate that it isn't unique. https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Str.php#L174-L217  If OpenSSL is available, you get a more random string, but otherwise, it is just an array shuffle of characters.

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be an issue, since a password reset code should be tied to a user account anyway, making it a composite key, and therefore unique.

All it needs to be is random, not a unique string, since the user should have to enter their email address as well as the password reset code in order for it to work. So if Bob and James both has the reset string of 12345, then them entering it would not be a conflict, since bob would enter bob@example.com 12345 and james would enter james@acme.com 12345; therefore they are both unique.

That is not to say that you shouldn't have random strings, you certainly should. The string should never be guessable. But as to whether it is completely unique, it does not matter.

Comment: --That would be fine, because it is assigned per user; so there is no issue with duplicate values.-- Ignore left. See comment below

Comment: What you need to do is ass in the check (the where(code)) to check the username / email that they provide as well. You need to check more than just hte reset code, check the username they are associated with too.

Comment: how can I access another function to grab the email input

Comment: They already provide their email, since you are validating their email.

Comment: but that is in another function

Comment: Is this part of a link they click in an email? If so, add their email to the link

Comment: but I want to do that without adding their email to the link

Comment: Okay, then I would suggest Carpetsmoker's method to making it unique, if you do not wish to turn it into a composite key.

Comment: @apache why you don't extend your function with the email address? I.e. `function recover($code, $mail)`? then you can query your user for the code and the mailaddress.

Comment: how can I pass two parameter to here URL::route('account-recover',$code)  instead of just $code I want to also pass $mail how can I do that

Answer (score 2):

If it's generating random output then it will occasionally recreate the same result. With a 60 character random string, the odds of that are ridiculously small, though.

Comment: For security functions, *'ridiculously small'* is usually not good enough; A famous example is the `mktemp()` function (in C), where there was a *'ridiculously small'* chance of creating a duplicate file or a race condition; however, attackers proved to be smart enough to exploit this....

Comment: I'm reasonably certain this person isn't working on an ultra-important low level piece of software where it would really matter. ;)

Comment: That is the wrong assumption. A lot of security leaks have been exploited because someone assumed "no one's going to try". That was fine, and then someone *did* try. Oops! Coding secure by default is usually *very* little extra effort, and may save a lot of headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not unique by definition as was already mentioned in another answers.

Second, it could be not random enough for the purpose even if OpenSSL is in the place. There was [a bug in PHP implementation of OpenSSL](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70014) giving tons of collisions which is fixed in the following versions:

- > = 5.4.44
- > = 5.5.28
- > = 5.6.13
- > = 7.0.0

So I advice not using it for security-related purpose.